# How to remove active OEM (EFI System) partition from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I recently bought a new Asus laptop with Windows 8 on it. After a week of hating it, I did a clean install of Windows 7 on the machine. I had to disable SecureBoot in the BIOS to even be able install Windows 7 from disk. Anyway, the installation went fine, and I'm running Windows 7.

In Computer Management in Windows 7 I found an old OEM (EFI System) partition which I would like to remove. But I want to do this without formatting the entire drive, as Windows is now working really well.

This is my current setup of partitions. I want to merge that first nameless partition with G: if at all possible. Computer Management doesn't allow me to do anything with that locked partition.

[image]

I tried to remove it with DiskPart.exe [With this tutorial](http://noaveragegeek.com/deleting-the-windows-7-oem-partition)

But it told me I could not remove system directories.

Is there anyway I can keep Windows 7 working, but remove that annoying locked partition?

Comment: It is, because i was asked to post it here instead of on StackOverflow.

Comment: and as you clearly can see, the first question was moved here to Superuser, thus no need to ask it again OR fail to delete this second one after the fact.  Since you left this second one up, it is tagged as a duplicate of the first.  You appear to be making a habit of asking a question twice at any rate (asus N55SF screen?)